# Display an image from the Linux console

Tags: c, linux, image, bash, embedded-linux

I've created a minimal Linux system which boots to the console and does not contain any kind of graphical environment.

I now want to display an image file from my C program or a bash script on the screen.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you gone through LFS , BLFS projects?

Comment: If your system has a framebuffer device, there's the **fbv** utility for JPEG, GIF and PNG images.  See http://free-electrons.com/blog/super-fast-linux-splashscreen/

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `/dev/fb0` works really well.

Answer (score 5):

If your system has a framebuffer device, i.e. **/dev/fb0**, then there's the [fbv](http://s-tech.elsat.net.pl/fbv) framebuffer viewer utility for JPEG, GIF, PNG, and BMP images. (It's available as a target package in Buildroot.)
And if you have a suitable raw image (e.g. a framebuffer capture), then that file can be written directly to the framebuffer device.
See [Super fast Linux splashscreen](http://free-electrons.com/blog/super-fast-linux-splashscreen/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options.

- If you have no “graphics” hardware, *per se*, you can use something like `libaa` or `libcaca` to convert an image into “ASCII ART.”
- If you have PC-type VGA-type hardware available (at least), you can use something like `svgalib` to write to the hardware, eg, using `zgv`
- If your device has a video framebuffer, you can write directly to the framebuffer device, as well.